# Как перенести laravel на хостинг?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется сайт на локальном хосте написанный на laravel.
Как его перенести на хост, помимо того, что его нужно залить в корень сайта?

Answer (score 1):

Ты не уточнил какой хостинг.
Если шаред, то возможно придется переименовать папку pulbic_html в public или сделать симлинк.

Если VPS, то проблем быть не должно, конечно если он настроен.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос, но мало уточнений нюансов, проект просто в локальной папке и заливать планируете по ftp? Если да, то требования к хостингу указаны в документации, нужно будет выставить атрибуты папок и файлов storage и bootstrap на 775, если умеете конфигурировать сервер и дать права на выполнение правильному пользователю, иначе 777. Ну и вопрос с public и public_html, но тут уже вам ответили.

Answer (score 0):

Делаю все с помощью Git:

1 Захожу в папку public_html

2 Делаю git clone

3 Тут будет папка с проектом. По этому нужно создать .htaccess c редиректом в папку public проекта. Например:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     
Project/public/$1 [L]     
</IfModule>
```

4 Копирую .env файл и делаю вписываю настройки БД и т.д...

5 composer i && composer update

6 php artisan key:generate

7 php artisan migrate

Все :)